# How to end a 'debug' mode?

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio, r-faq

In RStudio, I started a debug mode by

```
debug(ls)
ls()
```

Then I do not know how to end this mode. 
The prompt changed to

```
Browse[2]>
```

How can I end this debugging mode?

Comment: Esc doesn't end debug. You need to use `Q` then enter. (NB: If you are trying to see the value of an object named `Q` during debug, use `print(Q)`)

Comment: My bad.  I thought `ESC` did end debug mode.

Comment: You also have a stop button in RStudio, just above console

Comment: When in debug mode type the word `help` at the `Browse[]>` prompt to get a list of debug commands.

Comment: Cue a certain musical composition by Paul Dukas...

Answer (score 78):

First quit debugging the function with `Q` at the `Browse[2]>` prompt as jbaums tells you in his comment.  This takes you back to the `>` prompt.  Now turn off the debugging on `ls` with this command:

```
undebug(ls)
```

`?debug` is helpful for this sort of thing.

Comment: Wow. R must have been developed on a different planet. You can't just hit ctrl-d or type "exit", "out of here!", you need to remember what the function name is. R is so alien and we'll be stuck with it for many years to come...

Comment: Part of the problem is that hardly anyone uses R itself, most users are on RStudio and a lot of these features are simple buttons in RStudio, rather than these totally obscure commands.

Answer (score 16):

Use `debugonce()` instead of `debug()`. As the name suggests, this will only take the function through debug mode once. When in debug mode hit continue to run through the end or the next breakpoint or use the stop button to end the debug session.